# Sending http requests with Openresty to Google Analytics

Tags: nginx, lua, http2, openresty, measurement-protocol

I have been using openresty/nginx+lua to send server-side hits to Google Analytics Measurement Protocol.
However, the function I'm using (`ngx.location.capture`) is incompatible with HTTP/2 and a "won't fix" issue.
Apparently, the way to go is to use the 'resty.http' module. I must be doing something wrong migrating, because it no longer sends the hits along.

Here's the code that works:

```
location /example {
    resolver 8.8.8.8 ipv6=off;
    access_by_lua_block  {
        local request = {
        v = 1,
        t = "pageview",
        tid = "UA-XXXXXXX-Y",
        cid = ngx.md5(ngx.var.remote_addr .. ngx.var.http_user_agent),
        uip = ngx.var.remote_addr,
        dp = ngx.var.request_uri,
        dr = ngx.var.http_referer,
        ua = ngx.var.http_user_agent,
        ul = ngx.var.http_accept_language
        }

        local res = ngx.location.capture(  "/gamp",  {
        method = ngx.HTTP_POST,
        body = ngx.encode_args(request)
        })
    }
}

    location = /gamp {
    internal;
    expires epoch;
    access_log off;
    proxy_pass_request_headers off;
    proxy_pass_request_body on;
    proxy_pass https://google-analytics.com/collect;
    }
```

Here's how I tried and failed:

```
location /example {
        access_by_lua_block  {
                    local request = {
                    v = 1,
                    t = "pageview",
                    tid = "UA-XXXXXXX-Y",
                    cid = ngx.md5(ngx.var.remote_addr .. ngx.var.http_user_agent),
                    uip = ngx.var.remote_addr,
                    dp = ngx.var.request_uri,
                    dr = ngx.var.http_referer,
                    ua = ngx.var.http_user_agent,
                    ul = ngx.var.http_accept_language
                    }

            local http = require "resty.http"
            local httpc = http.new()
            local res, err = httpc:request_uri("https://google-analytics.com/collect", {
            method = "POST",
            body = ngx.encode_args(request)
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried logging out the `err` error from the call to `request_uri`?

Comment: Should the `ngx.encode_args(request)` output perhaps be stored in the `query` property of `params` instead of `body?`

Comment: Not sure if I'm logging properly, but when I try to it all fails with:

2019/10/03 16:39:19 [notice] 13572#13572: signal 3 (SIGQUIT) received from 14346, shutting down
2019/10/03 16:39:19 [notice] 13574#13574: gracefully shutting down
2019/10/03 16:39:19 [notice] 13574#13574: exiting
2019/10/03 16:39:19 [notice] 13574#13574: exit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add two more directives: `resolver` and `lua_ssl_trusted_certificate`.

For example,

```
server {
  ...
  resolver 8.8.8.8 ipv6=off;
  lua_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt;
  # optional
  # lua_ssl_verify_depth 5;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Yep, thanks, this works, I missed the certificate thing completely. I was late to award the bounty, I restarted it and and will give it as soon as the system allows.